# I am getting Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, qsort

I am getting error on the line where I put "`<<--`" (line 9) sign. it didn't had any compiling error , but while giving input it says "Segmentation fault: 11". I don't know what went wrong.

input:

```
3 3
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 1 5
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp (const void * x, const void * y)
{
   int *a = *(int **)x;
   int *b = *(int **)y;

   //getting error here

   if (a[0] == b[0])   // <<-- here
   {
        if (a[2] == b[2])
        {
            return -(a[1] - b[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            return a[2] - b[2];
        }
   }
   else
   {
       return a[0] - b[0];
   }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    long long d;
    scanf("%d %lld", &n, &d);

    int t[n][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d %d %d", &t[i][0], &t[i][1], &t[i][2]);
    }

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(t[0]));
    qsort(t, n, sizeof(t[0]), comp);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n", t[i][0], t[i][1], t[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.   Have you printed the addresses contained in `a` and `b` in the comparator?  Why not?  Have you tried using a debugger with a break point set on the comparator?

Comment: Note that your code will have problems with input where the number of elements in each line is not 3 (so if the first line of data contains `10 4`, your code will not handle the size 4 correctly).  That is not immediately critical — your code is, it seems, crashing when the second parameter is `3`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when wanting input from the user, display a prompt that tells the user what is needed.  Otherwise the user is left with a blank screen, with a blinking cursor and no idea of what to do next

Comment: i am solving a question where the input is described as such                          input :The first line of input contains two integers "N D", the number of workers and the area of your house respectively. The ith of the next N lines denotes the ith worker, and contains three integers "Ti Xi Yi", described in the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
int t[n][3];
```

array is actually an 1D array consisting of `n` 1D arrays of type `int [3]`. These `int [3]` objects is what you are trying to sort by your

```
qsort(t, n, sizeof(t[0]), comp)
```

call.

So, in order to properly compare these objects you have to interpret the parameters of your comparison callback as pointers to `int [3]` objects. Meanwhile, your current implementation of `comp` is written as if the parameters are pointing to `int *` objects, which is incorrect. `int [3]` and `int *` are two very different things.

This is how you can do it

```
int comp (const void * x, const void * y)
{
  int (*a)[3] = x;
  int (*b)[3] = y;

  // And now compare the arrays by accessing them as `(*a)[1]`, 
  // `(*b)[2]` and so on
}
```

Alternatively, you can write the `comp` prologue code as

```
int comp (const void * x, const void * y)
{
  const int *a = *(int (*)[3]) x;
  const int *b = *(int (*)[3]) y;

  // And now compare the arrays by accessing them as `a[1]`, 
  // `b[2]` and so on, i.e. keep the rest of your code unchanged
}
```

This assumes that the rest of your comparison logic is correct. Note though that comparing `int` values by subtracting them from each other is risky, since it can overflow.

Comment: sir your first solution is showing error. "initializing 'int (*)[3]' with an expression of type 'const void *' discards qualifiers
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]"                                          this code works "int (*a)[3] = (int (*)[3]) x;
   int (*b)[3] = (int (*)[3]) y;" instead